# Display file with ANSI colors

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a file with ANSI colors.

test.txt:
`\e[0;31mExample\e[0m`

I would like to display the content of this file in a terminal, like `cat` does, but I would like to display the colors as well.

Comment: Using `less -R`, for instance.

Comment: What does your `cat` print?

Comment: OP's question had too many possible answers to be interesting.  Start with `echo -e $(cat test.txt)`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to this exact bash question. I nearly missed @Thomas Dickey's comment which provided me with the most elegant solution.

```
echo -e $(cat test.txt)
```

Some things which did not work for me are(apparently you cant pipe things to echo)

```
cat test.txt | echo -e
```

or

```
less -R test.txt
```

Another issue I had was that echo -e didn't print newlines and contiguous whitespaces within the file nicely. To print those, I used the following.

```
echo -ne $(cat test.txt | sed  's/$/\\n/' | sed 's/ /\\a /g')
```

This works for a test.txt file containing

```
\e[0;31mExa         mple\e[0m
\e[0;31mExample line2\e[0m
```

Comment: Good answer, but `\a` rings the bell for me. I changed your second sed command to `sed 's/ /\\033\\a /g'` which doesn't ring the bell.

Comment: After further testing and finding more inconsistencies in different terminal programs (iTerm, Atom/nuclide), I've found it best to just wrap `$(cat file.txt)` in double quotes and add a newline at the end – no need for sed – so: `echo -ne "$(<file.txt)" \\n` or `echo -ne "$(cat <<"EOF" . . . EOF)" \\n`. That also prevents bash from performing glob expansion in the text.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not seeing color from `cat` the control characters are probably not intact.

Some tools strip out control characters but leave in the tail end.

Compare:

```
 echo -e "\e[0;31mExample\e[0m foo"
```

to

```
 echo -e "[0;31mExample[0m foo"
```

You might be able to rebuild the control sequence from what's left, though it's not fool proof as the regex you use might accidentally pull in unintended character sequences, etc. But for example:

```
echo -e "[0;31mExample[0m foo" | sed "s:\[\([0-9]*[;m]\):^[[\1:g"
```

would restore the color to the example string.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package that contains an executable that is specifically does this:

```
ttyrec
```

You can install it on Debian derived Linux installations with either

```
sudo apt install ttyrec
```

or on RedHat ones with

```
sudo yum install ttyrec
```

The command to replay a file properly is executed with

```
ttyplay <filename>
```

Also checkout a package named tty2gif, which converts similar files to gif.

Answer (score 0):

It should work by default.
E.g. if I do `ls --color=always > /tmp/a` and than `cat /tmp/a`, I see the colors. Checking with `od` confirms that the file uses ANSI colors.

So I think you should check if your terminal supports ANSI colors (and they are enabled).

Comment: This did not answer the question.

Comment: No. less -R actually resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Giacomo Catenazzi is right. If the file contains valid escape sequences, the `cat` will display them. Since `cat` does not interpret sequences like `echo -e` does, the file should really contain single [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character) HEX 1B at the beginning of a colour sequence, not `\033` or `\x1B` or similar.