# Piping curl http://cheat.sh/python to less is showing strange ESC[38;5;246m

Tags: shell-script, shell, curl, less, streams

I am kinda new to Linux.

My base issue: I need to show the output of `curl cheat.sh/python` like a `man` or `less` page, so that I can easily scroll up and down.

What have I tried: `curl cheat.sh/python | less`

outout: some weird text like this-

> ESC[38;5;246m# Python is a high-level programming languageESC[39m
>   ESC[38;5;246m# and python is a Python interpreter.ESC[39m
>
> ESC[38;5;246m# Basic example of server with pythonESC[39m
>   ESC[38;5;246m# Will start a Web Server in the current directory on
>   port 8 000ESC[39m ESC[38;5;246m# go to http://127.0.0.1:8000ESC[39m
>   ESC[38;5;246m#ESC[39m ESC[38;5;246m# Python v2.7ESC[39m
>   ESC[38;5;252mpythonESC[39mESC[38;5;252m
>   ESC[39mESC[38;5;252m-mESC[39mESC[ 38;5;252m
>   ESC[39mESC[38;5;252mSimpleHTTPServerESC[39m ESC[38;5;246m# Python
>   3ESC[39m ESC[38;5;252mpythonESC[39mESC[38;5;252m
>   ESC[39mESC[38;5;252m-mESC[39mESC[ 38;5;252m
>   ESC[39mESC[38;5;252mhttp.serverESC[39mESC[38;5;252m ESC[39mESC[
>   38;5;67m8000ESC[39m ...

After having a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427454/how-do-i-pipe-or-redirect-the-output-of-curl-v), I tried: `curl -vs cheat.sh 2>&1 | less`

but output was kinda same:

> Accept: */* 
>   * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.13.12 Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 17:50:04 GMT Content-Type:
>
> text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 25502 Connection: keep-alive
>
> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
>
> X-Frame-Options: DENY X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff  { [2429 bytes data]
>   ESC[38;2;0;204;0m_ESC[0mESC[38;2;0;204;0m_ESC[0mESC[38;2;0;204;0m
>   ESC[0mESC[38;2;0;204;0m ESC[0mESC[38;2;0; 204;0m ESC[0m
>   ***| |***     **__ *| |*   _**| |__ ESC[38;2;0;204;0m\ESC[0mESC[38;2;0;204;0m
>   ESC[0mESC[38;2;0;204;0m\ESC[0mESC[38;2;0;204;0m ESC[0mESC[38;2;0;
>   204;0m ESC[0m ESC[48;2;85;85;85m ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85m
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85m
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mTESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mhESC[0mESC[48
>   ;2;85;85;85meESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85m
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85moESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mnESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mlESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85myESC[0m
>   ESC[48;2;85;85;85m
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mcESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mhESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85meESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85maESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mt
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85m
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85msESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mhESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85meESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85meESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85
>   ;85mtESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85m
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85myESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85moESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85muESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85m
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;
>   85;85;85mnESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85meESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85meESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85mdESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85m
>   ESC[0mESC[48;2;85;85;85m ESC[0mESC[ 48;2;85;85;85m ESC[0m ...

Finally if I change the above code like (this is probably the wrong approach) : `curl -vs cheat.sh 1>&2 | less`

Then I will get the needed output of curl, but upon pressing a button the terminal shows like:

> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~
>
> ~ (END)
>   and I can basically press q to quit out of `less` from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display file with ANSI colors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262185/display-file-with-ansi-colors) – `less -R`?

Comment: Yes. Thankyou. I didn't know the issue was with interpreting colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-R` option of `less`, so that it interprets these codes as colour.
It is rendering the codes in a human readable way. However can pass them to the terminal to be interpreted as colour. `-r` passes everything to terminal, `-R` only does this for colour.

`curl cheat.sh/python | less -R`

Comment: Yes. Thankyou. I didn't know the issue was with interpreting colors.